how to use qml to get the mouse position in my screen not in the application
I want to write a function that querying global mouse position, my code is here
Window {
    id: root
    color: transparentColor
    visibility: ApplicationWindow.FullScreen
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint
    MouseArea {
        id: mainMouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true

        onPositionChanged: {
            mouseCoordinatesText.x = mainMouseArea.mouseX + 10;
            mouseCoordinatesText.y = mainMouseArea.mouseY + 10;
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: mouseCoordinatesText
        text: "Mouse Coordinates: (" + Math.floor(mainMouseArea.mouseX) + ", " + Math.floor(mainMouseArea.mouseY) + ")"
        color: "white"
        visible: true
    }
}

when I run this code,I can see that the window fill with my screen, but when I get this positon, it seems not suit for my screen resolution
what can I do to get the mouse real position in my screen

Does https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToGlobal-method help?

@StephenQuan I try this functon, but I find that the value exceed my screen resolution. it's max value was 2970,1627, but my screen just 1920,1080

text: "Mouse Coordinates: (" + Math.floor(mainMouseArea.mouseX) + ", " + Math.floor(mainMouseArea.mouseY) + ")\n"
              + mapToGlobal(mainMouseArea.mouseX,mainMouseArea.mouseY)

I use like this

Sounds like a dpi res aware issue. To verify set you windows scale to 100% and try again. You can take into account dpi scale when dpi is not 100% with a number of different ways.

@StephenQuan Thank you very much, I find that It was a dpi issue.
